# Finding all possible adjacent/closest geometrical points from a given point

Tags: python, point, geopandas, shapely, pandas

So, I have a dataframe like this,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import descartes
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'Address':['280 Broadway','1 Liberty Island','141 John Street'],
                   'Latitude':[ 40.71,40.69,40.71],
                   'Longitude':[-74.01,-74.05,-74.00]
                    }) 


%matplotlib inline

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip( df["Longitude"],df["Latitude"])]
crs = {'init':'epsg:4326'}
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,
                     crs=crs,
                    geometry=geometry)
df.head()
```

I converted the lat and lon to geometry points and I am trying to find all possible closest points for each address using the geometrical points. For example, all possible closest points adjacent to 280 Broadway which lies next to each other for one block.There could be more than one point if the points are adjacent to each other containing in a polygon shape.

This was my approach but didn't really get what I wanted,

```
df.insert(4, 'nearest_geometry', None)
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint
from shapely.ops import nearest_points

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    point = row.geometry
    multipoint = df.drop(index, axis=0).geometry.unary_union
    queried_geom, nearest_geom = nearest_points(point, multipoint)
    df.loc[index, 'nearest_geometry'] = nearest_geom
```

Desired Output:

```
Address       Lat     Lon    geometry                    nearest_points
280 Broadway  40.71  -74.01  POINT (-74.01000 40.71000)  POINT(NEAREST GEOMETRIC POINT)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with latitudes and longitudes, I'd suggest you work with the haversine formula, which gives the great-circle distance between two points on a sphere. To return the k nearest neighbors, you could go for something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

# the formula requires rad instead of degree
dataframe[["lat_rad", "lon_rad"]] = np.deg2rad(dataframe[["Latitude", "Longitude"]])

ball_tree = BallTree(dataframe[["lat_rad", "lon_rad"]], metric="haversine")

neighbors = ball_tree.query(
    dataframe[["lat_rad", "lon_rad"]],
    k=(
        k + 1
    ),  # k + 1 because we remove the address itself later, hence we need k - 1 = k_desired
    return_distance=False,  # choose whether you also want to return the distance
    sort_results=True,
)

# remove the address/point itself from the array because it itself is its nearest neighbour
neighbors = neighbors[:, 1:]

# select the nearest addresses by position index
dataframe["nearest_addresses"] = [
    dataframe["Address"].iloc[n].to_list() for n in neighbors
]

dataframe.explode("nearest_addresses")[["Address", "nearest_addresses"]]
```

with dataframe being a pandas DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about geopandas specifically, but I would use `shapely`'s `STRTree` for this task. It has a `nearest` method:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.strtree import STRtree

points = [
    Point(1, 1),
    Point(2, 2),
    Point(3, 3)
]

tree = STRtree(points)

print(tree.nearest(Point(0, 0)).wkt)
print(tree.nearest(Point(5, 5)).wkt)
```

This will yield

```
POINT (1 1)
POINT (3 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using scipy.spatials KDTree which is used to find the list k nearest neighbors. I have set k=2 since the nearest neighbor is itself. We get the result neighs which is an array of indexes for example neighs[0] = [0,j] where j is the index of it's nearest neighbor of the point at index 0. I then slice this array so it's just the nearest neighbor. Then I access the points and add a column to the df.

```
from scipy import spatial

# get list of points
points = df['geometry'].apply(
                lambda g:[g.x,g.y]).tolist()
#spatially organising the points on a tree for quick nearest neighbors calc
kdtree = spatial.KDTree(points)

#calculates the nearest neighbors of each point
_ , neighs = kdtree.query(centroids, k=2)

# remove itself as neighbor
neighs = neighs[:,1]

# add column to df
df['nearest_points'] = df.iloc[neighs, 3].tolist()
```